# Fake Viewport in HTML

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to "fake" a viewport in HTML? By this I mean, I'm viewing on a browser, but I want one piece of content to render exactly as it would on a mobile device.

I got half way there trivially by just wrapping the content in a div with the width/height set to the size of the device I want to "emulate", but CSS rules defined with the min/max width property don't work here as they are looking at the width of the screen, not the width of the parent.

I'm hoping for something like

```
<fakeviewport width=768 height=1024>
Some content I want to render like it would on a tablet that respects CSS rules.
</fakeviewport>
```

Answer (score 0):

iframe is very similar to what you asked for.
these websites may be of help to you
[: The Inline Frame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)
and [A tale of two viewports](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html)

Comment: Hello...
Inspect // Watch ...
Your answer is poorly elaborated.
It is useful to insert an effective response, with codes and references. Concluding a practical and efficient solution.
This platform is not just any forum. We are the largest help and support center for other programmers and developers in the world. Review the terms of the community and learn how to post;